# How to pattern match a transformed Vec<String> in Rust idiomatically?

Tags: string, vector, rust, pattern-matching

Given a variable `tokens: &Vec<String>`, I would like to do the following:

1. Validate it: a valid `tokens` must start with `"abc"`, `"def"` and end with `"xyz"` (type-coersedly speaking?), and the equality is case-insensitive.
2. In case of a valid `tokens`, extract the rest of the `tokens` for later processing.

What I tried:

```rust
fn process_tokens(tokens: &Vec<String>) -> Result<(), &str> {
    let lowercased_tokens: Vec<String> = tokens.iter().map(|s| s.to_lowercase()).collect();
    match lowercased_tokens.iter().map(|s| s as &str).collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice() {
        ["abc", "def", remaining_tokens @ .., "xyz"] => { 
            // do something with remaining_tokens
            Ok(())
        }
        _ => Err ("Invalid tokens!")
    }
}
```

My problem with this:

1. A temporary vector `lowercased_tokens` was created, which seems performance-wise not ideal
2. Verbose

However, I have difficulties finding how to achieve what I want without:

1. Without the temporary vector, the lowercased tokens generated in the method chaining is "temporary" and we cannot apply `|s| s as &str` to them.
2. In the other direction, I don't know how to pattern match a `Vec<String>`, i.e., putting `"abc".to_string()` instead of `"abc"` in the matching pattern (which is invalid syntax).

Comment: AFAIK, you can not currently do pattern matching like `["abc", ...]` without having a `[&str]`. However, there is work on [deref patterns](https://github.com/rust-lang/lang-team/issues/88) which would allow this to theoretically work on `&lowercased_tokens` directly. This was explicitly mentioned in the Rust team's recent [2024 roadmap blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/inside-rust/2022/04/04/lang-roadmap-2024.html) so there's some real desire behind it. It would make code like this more ergonomic and apply to more types than just `Vec` and `String`.

Answer (score 4):

My suggestion would be to work with a slice of strings (`&[String]`)<sup>1</sup>, as you can "peel off" the elements you are validating.  We can wrap this up into two functions: one that expects something at the start and one that expects something at the end.  The comparisons can be done case-insensitively to prevent allocation of additional strings.  Both functions will return a subslice with the expected element removed.

Doing it this way requires no additional allocations, as the slice is just a fat pointer into the vector's own allocation.

```
fn expect_start<'a>(expected: &'_ str, strs: &'a [String])
    -> Result<&'a [String], &'static str>
{
    match strs.first() {
        Some(v) if expected.eq_ignore_ascii_case(v) => Ok(&strs[1..]),
        _ => Err("unexpected token at start of string"),
    }
}

fn expect_end<'a>(expected: &'_ str, strs: &'a [String])
    -> Result<&'a [String], &'static str>
{
    match strs.last() {
        Some(v) if expected.eq_ignore_ascii_case(v) => Ok(&strs[..(strs.len() - 1)]),
        _ => Err("unexpected token at end of string"),
    }
}
```

Now we can easily combine these into the `process_tokens` function, bailing whenever we encounter an error (using `?`):

```
fn process_tokens(mut tok: &[String]) -> Result<(), &'static str> {
    tok = expect_start("abc", tok)?;
    tok = expect_start("def", tok)?;
    tok = expect_end("xyz", tok)?;
    
    // Do something with tok
    println!("Remaining tokens: {:?}", tok);
    Ok(())
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3712ca375feb1461d53cbe9587804018))

---

<sup>1</sup> These functions could work with `&str` just as easily as `String`, but accepting a slice of `&str` would require creating a second vector to hold the slices referencing the strings in the first vector.  However, you can alter these functions to accept slices of `String` or `&str` by accepting `&[T]` where `T: Borrow<str>`, as both `String` and `&str` implement this trait.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do feel the `String` `&str` part in rust quite confusing. I am not totally convinced by the solution because it introduces two helper functions to the code, and it forces us to give up the power of pattern matching in general (especially the exhaustion of cases). But after a second thought, this may imply that pattern matching is not really designed for data validation because validation always reject all remaining cases. Thus pattern matching is unnecessary.

Comment: @ClémentDato `String` is an owned heap allocation of contiguous bytes, which must be valid UTF-8. `&str` is a borrowed region of the same. Therefore, you can borrow a `&str` from a `String`.

Comment: @ClémentDato I've used slice+str pattern matching for tokens->ast processing before and been fairly successful. So I don't think `match` is necessarily the wrong tool, just your data structure does not lend itself to being matched nicely. In lieu of that, these helper functions seem like the next best thing.